# Making curl command to work using curl in r for the DVLA MOT data

Tags: r, api, curl

I'm getting very lost trying to write a curl command in r using the curl package.

The curl command I have is

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json+v3" -H "x-api-key: XXXXX" \https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?page=[0-58002]
```

I've tried the following

```
library(curl)
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h);
handle_setheaders(h,
                  'page'='[0-58002]',
                  'Accept' = 'application/json',
                  'x-api-key' = 'XXXXX'

)


tmp <- tempfile()
curl_download("https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests", destfile = tmp, handle = h)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? I know that the initial curl command works, just not the r version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want

```
library(curl)
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, verbose = TRUE)
handle_setheaders(h, .list = list(
              'Accept' = 'application/json',
              'x-api-key' = 'XXXXX')

)
tmp <- tempfile()
curl_download("https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests?page=[0-58002]", destfile = tmp, handle = h)
```

`handle_setopt(h, verbose = TRUE)` to get verbose curl output, will help you debug any problems. the query parameter goes in the url, not in the headers

Comment: It turns out I spoke too soon. This works for curl_download("https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests?page=1", destfile = tmp, handle = h) but as soon as I try to get more than 1 page at a time it falls over

Comment: Some more detail: The error response coming back from the API is "400 – bad request Invalid data in the request. Check your URL and parameters"

Comment: are you sure you're allowed to get more than 1 page at a time?

Comment: I'm probably missing something but i can't see how to https://www.check-mot.service.gov.uk/mot-history-api